# Referencing an array in bash / redirection to a loop

Tags: arrays, bash, redirect

I'm trying to use redirection (learning purposes) and was wondering how i can reference this array  so i can iterate through it. i know there are other ways but i'm trying to stick with redirection.

```
#!/bin/bash
count=0
for i in  10.10.{0..255}.{0..255}
do
ips[$count]=$i
let count+=1
done

echo -e "$count = count\n" #test code for amount

#problem code: trying to feed the array to the while loop via redirection
while read $element; do
echo -en "$element\n"
done < ${ips[@]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<<<` to redirect a string (vice `<` which accepts file names). This is not the most natural way to loop over an array: you also have to use `read -d' '` to split on spaces instead of on newlines.

```
while read -d' ' $element; do
    echo -en "$element\n"
done <<< "${ips[@]}"
```

For comparison, the more idiomatic way of looping over an array would be:

```
for ip in "${ips[@]}"; do
    echo -en "$ip\n"
done
```

---

Also, for what it's worth, you could simplify the first loop to:

```
for i in 10.10.{0..255}.{0..255}; do
    ips+=($i)
done
```

Or even simply:

```
ips=(10.10.{0..255}.{0..255})
```

Comment: thanks for the clarification. that makes sense instead of iterating through the array to get a count. one more question about references, can you explain what's going on in this statement (total break down) like what exactly does $(something) do? does the hashsign reference something? thanks.

`${#ips[@]}`

Comment: The hash sign gets the number of items in the array. `${ips[@]}` is the list of addresses and `${#ips[@]}` is the count.